# can not call functions in function.php

Tags: functions, static-website

In front-page.php I have the following code:

```
<span class="amountOnline">
     Online:
     <?php echo $cbMain->GetInfo()['Players'] . '/' . $cbMain->GetInfo()['MaxPlayers']; ?>
</span>
```

Which is a function in functions.php that calls from [this script](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query/blob/master/MinecraftQuery.class.php#L57).It works perfectly.

But once I move this code from `front-page.php` to `header.php`, I get the following error:'

```
Notice: Undefined variable: cbMain in C:\Users\...\header.php on line 102

Fatal error: Call to a member function GetInfo() on a non-object in C:\Users\...\header.php on line 102
```

In functions.php, I have this function for example:

```
function get_cbMain_Query() {
  define( 'Main_SERVER_ADDR', '0.0.0.0');
  define( 'Main_SERVER_PORT', 25565);
  define( 'Main_TIMEOUT', 1 );

  // require bloginfo('template_url') . 'inc/avatars/MinecraftQuery.class.php';
  require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/mcQuery/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

  Error_Reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
  Ini_Set( 'display_errors', true );

  $Timer = MicroTime( true );
  $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

  try
  {
    $Query->Connect( Main_SERVER_ADDR, Main_SERVER_PORT, Main_TIMEOUT );
  }
  catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
  {
   // $Error = $e->getMessage();
   // echo 'error. <br>'. $Error;
  }
  return $Query;
}
```

Then

`$cbMain = get_cbMain_Query();`

So I can use functions in my static front-page.php file, but once I move this script to header.php, it does not work and gives an error. How do I fix this?

Comment: this has nothing to do with WordPress, it's a generic PHP problem, namely one of _scope_. You can't declare variables in one scope then use them in another without a connecting action of some kind such as a declaring in both places that it's a global variable or a step to retrieve and set the variable when it's used

Answer (score 1):

The content of your `header.php` is called with `get_header()`, so all variales inside of this file act in another [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) than the calling file.

So either get the variable from the global scope or build a wrapper in your `functions.php` to access the object from anywhere:

```
function get_cbmain() 
{
    static $instance = NULL;

    NULL === $instance and $instance = new MinecraftQuery;

    return $instance;
}
```

Now you can get the object instance with:

```
get_cbmain()->GetInfo();
```

Comment: Thank you! It seemed to work, kinda. Look at my edit and see how I set the code up. I can't just use new MinecraftQuery because I use two of these same classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your class instance is not in the scope of `header.php`, you need `global $cbMain` before accessing member functions.